# Case owner should be updated to Created by field

Tags: trigger, administration

Is there anyway that I could update "Case Owner" in Case object to the "created by" Field value using the Workflow? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Out of the box it's supposed to work like that. If your owner changes it indicates some assignment rules, workflows or triggers that change it. Check the debug log, maybe you'll find something and for example build an exception into the assignments? Or change some apex controller to not use assignment rules if it's on 1 special page that you need it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be via workflow as workflows require specific users to be specified for the owner, or a case queue.

You could do this with a quick trigger (warning: untested code!)

```
trigger Case_BeforeInsertUpdate(before insert, before update)
{
  for(Case c : trigger.new)
  {
    c.OwnerId = c.CreatedById;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with workflow because you would need to specify the specific user beforehand, it is not dynamic.  A trigger must be used here.